# How to hide panel by specific condition in grafana

Tags: grafana

I want to hide some panel by specific condition in graphana.
For instance, I have some variable in my dashboard and I want to change visibility of some graph if my variable is equal to some specific value. 
Is there any way to do this?

UPD: Using repeat panel option is not solution in my case, because this option just dynamically creates new panels. But I want to hide some panel by specific value of my variable, if variable is not equal to this value then the panel should not be hidden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide grafana panels based on selected template variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257014/hide-grafana-panels-based-on-selected-template-variable)

Comment: here is the same question ... without answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808424/grafana-dashboard-show-hide-row-based-on-variable-value 
Seems like there is no such option in grafana and never will be :(

Answer (score 3):

I dont see an option to hide/show a panel with template variable, but instead you can create two dashboards and use dashboard links.

For example:

First Dashboard (Type A)
Second Dashboard (Type B)

Create a Dashboard link "Type B" in First Dashboard pointing to second Dashboard.
Similarly Create a Dashboard link "Type A" in Second Dashboard and point it to First dashboard.

Settings -> Link -> New Link -> Choose "Include time range" & "Include template variable value"

[image: New Dashboard Link]

I have actually used this option because mine was just two variables so it was duplicating the dashboard to two and linking eachother.

[image]

If it is multiple values to show/hide, i recommend to achieve it via repeat options some how linking that variable in your query.