# Grafana Dashboard show/hide row based on variable value

Tags: go, grafana, grafana-variable

So, I have a Grafana dashboard to show the logs of various services running inside a host.

Now, I have different rows for different service because metrics and there titles are specific to the service - Such as for Apache Service, we have log metrics based on HTTP STATUS CODE, for Oracle Database Service, we have ORA-* distribution, connection partition /trend etc.

Now, My question is simple that the Grafana dashboard supports repeat on rows and individual metrics. How can I use this feature to show/ hide my rows based on variable values selected.

Here it says that it will never be implemented ( https://community.grafana.com/t/hiding-a-row-panel/1788/3 ),

and this question([Hide grafana panels based on selected template variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257014/hide-grafana-panels-based-on-selected-template-variable)) does asks the same thing but in the accepted answer only links are provided, which are of very little help.

Comment: Very unforunate. This would be usefull functionality in my mind. +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully imagine your dashboard / panel. However I've managed to hide rows from two of my panels using two different methods.

- **Method number 1**: You can remove rows with metrics with specific labels. This is done in the query like in - *(metric{label =~ "some regex"})*. All metrics with these labels will not be included.
- **Method number 2**: You can use Transform.*'Filter data by values'.'Filter type = Exclude'*. This will remove rows with values that correspond to the applied filter.

Comment: 2 is not working, it only removes the data, not the row